# incompatible types in subassignment type fix (R)

Tags: r, class, for-loop

I have the following code and error message that I'm not sure how to solve:

> require("XLConnect")
>
> wkb <- c(1:7)
>
> for (k in 1:7) {
>   +   wkb[k] <- loadWorkbook(paste("RNK", k, "1114.xls", sep=""))
>   + }

```
Error in wkb[(k - 9)] <- loadWorkbook(paste("RNK", k, "1114.xls", sep = "")) : 
  incompatible types (from S4 to integer) in subassignment type fix
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `wkb <- vector(mode='list', length=7)` instead of `wkb <- c(1:7)` to initialize your list.

In your `numeric` vector `c(1:7)`, you can only have elements of mode `numeric`, but `loadWorkbook` returns a `workbook`. Therefore you should use a `list` instead.